# ArrayBuffer inserting null element

Tags: java, mongodb, scala

I am trying to perform a bulkwrite using Scala and Mongodb. Currently, I am using an ArrayBuffer to buffer some documents and call the bulkwrite function after a while to make the save.

I have the following code:

```
def saveActivity(activity: Activity) {    
  saveCount += 1;
  val myDoc = Json.toJson(activity).toString  
  var doc: Document = Document(myDoc)
  doc += "initialTime" -> BsonDateTime.apply(activity.initialTime);
  doc += "endingTime" -> BsonDateTime.apply(activity.endingTime);     
  val fId = fileIdsMap.get(activity.file_id);
  doc += "file_id" -> fId;
  doc += "userId" -> usersMap.get(activity.meta.userId)

  if(doc == null)
    println("Inserting a null document!")

  activitiesBuffer.append(doc);

  if(saveCount % 1000 == 0) {
    bulkSave(activitiesBuffer);      
    activitiesBuffer.clear()
  }
}
```

And my code to save using bulkwrite is the following:

```
def bulkSave(batch:ArrayBuffer[Document]) {    
    val requests = batch.map(doc => {  
       if(doc == null)
        println(s"Found a null document");
       new InsertOneModel[Document](doc)       
      })    
    val observable = MongoFactory.MyCollection.bulkWrite(requests.toList, new BulkWriteOptions().ordered(false))
    val ed = Await.result(observable.toFuture, Duration.Inf).asInstanceOf[List[com.mongodb.bulk.BulkWriteResult]](0)        
    println(s"BULKWRITE FINISHED")

  }
```

And I the main loop is consuming jsons from a KafkaPool:

```
while (true) {          
  val records = consumer.poll(1000)          
  for (record <- records) {
    val json: JsValue = Json.parse(record.value())
    val arquivo = Json.fromJson[Activity](json);            
    val activity = json.as[Activity]
    saveActivity(activity)                                
  }              
}
```

The problem is that somehow a null document is being inserted in the middle of the arraybuffer.

The two prints are there to verify when there's a null document. (One in the `saveActivity` function and one in the `bulkSave` function. From these two, only the one inside the bulkwrite `map` function is called. The one that actually appends a document to the buffer is never called. I am getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: document can not be null
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: document can not be null  at
>   com.mongodb.assertions.Assertions.notNull(Assertions.java:37)     at
>   com.mongodb.client.model.InsertOneModel.(InsertOneModel.java:37)
>     at Translator$$anonfun$5.apply(Translator.scala:101)    at
>   Translator$$anonfun$5.apply(Translator.scala:96)  at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:245)
>     at
>   scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>     at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>     at
>   scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:245)
>     at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
>     at Translator.bulkSaveActivities(Translator.scala:96)   at
>   Translator.saveActivity(Translator.scala:146)     at
>   Translator.proccessActivity(Translator.scala:187)     at
>   Translator$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Translator.scala:263)
>     at
>   Translator$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Translator.scala:256)
>     at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)  at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)    at
>   scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)    at
>   scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)  at
>   Translator$$anon$1.run(Translator.scala:256)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

I tried to print the map batch and I saw this (Only a slice of it shown):

> ...Document((activityCount,BsonInt32{value=1}),
>   (initialTime,BsonDateTime{value=1448272800000}),
>   (endingTime,BsonDateTime{value=1448276400000}),
>   (account,BsonString{value='0'}),
>   (file_id,BsonString{value='58d1ed13c1728a63986a6052'}),
>   (userId,BsonString{value='58d1ed0dc1728a63986a52d8'})), ***null***,
>   Document((activityCount,BsonInt32{value=1}),
>   (initialTime,BsonDateTime{value=1432789200000}), (...

As you can see, there's a null element on it and I don't know how it went there. Anyone has any suggestion? Thanks in advance

Comment: Sorry, but this does not look like a real [mcve] to me - as you are only showing parts of your code ;but keep explaining other parts of it. I doubt that you will receive much useful answers on such input.

Comment: @GhostCat, thanks for your teachings. I tried to add more information and a bit more of explanation in the code. I believe this has all the parts to make it work and it has much less pseudo-code. Please, correct me again if I am wrong.

Comment: It looks much better now; but my problem is that I am neither into Kafka; nor  mongo DB, and my knowledge of Scala isn't too deep either. But at least ... if some more-expert-on-this person comes by, chances are higher for you to receive help ... and maybe you want to add a kafka tag ...

Comment: Thanks anyway, I also wanna be a top user one day, so your help was really helpful. I have nothing to do here but wait for a Scala OP to come and help me. :)

Comment: The only two advises I have: try adding more trace statements. When you dont understand what your code is doing, make it tell you what it is doing.